# Animate with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a series of view stacked this way

```
 ________________
|                |
|     View 1     |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 2     |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 3     |
|________________|
```

These view can be expanded and collapsed so if View 1 is expanded, View 2 has its top an the bottom of View 1, and the same for the View 3 related with the View 2.

```
 ________________
|                |
|     View 1     |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 2     |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 3     |
|________________|

 ________________
|                |
|     View 1     |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 2     |
|                |
|                |
|                |
|________________|
|                |
|     View 3     |
|________________|
```

I can't add these view via IB because this layout is created dinamycally so I have to add the views via code and the constraints too.

I'm doing this

```
UIView *previousView = nil;
for (UIView *view in views) {

    if (previousView) {

        NSArray *constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[previousView][view]"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(previousView, view)];

        [superview addConstraints:constraints];
    }
}
```

When I tap a view to expand it I'm receiving an error

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x76407b0 h=&-& v=--& V:[MyView:0x764c0f0(44)]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x763e370 h=&-& v=--& V:[MyView:0x7646490(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x76440d0 V:[MyView:0x764c0f0]-(0)-[MyView:0x7648eb0]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7643920 V:[MyView:0x7648eb0]-(0)-[MyView:0x7646490]>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x76407f0 h=&-& v=--& MyView:0x764c0f0.midY == + 22>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x76d9ea0 h=&-& v=--& MyView:0x7648eb0.midY == + 91.5>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x763e3b0 h=&-& v=--& MyView:0x7646490.midY == + 110>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7643920 V:[MyView:0x7648eb0]-(0)-[MyView:0x7646490]>
```

Obviously I'm doing this wrong. Do I have to set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO` and add my own constraints to the positioning? Or the problem is the constraint that I'm adding on that loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you changing the size of the view? You have a constraint fixing the vertical space between your two views at 0. Is the error you get showing you any other constraints (perhaps ones that you didn't add explicitly)? I suspect that there's probably another constraint on View 2 and/or View 3 which isn't allowing them to move down to satisfy the `V-[View 1]-(0)-[View 2]` constraint.

If there were no other constraints involved, simply changing the height of the view you want to expand or collapse should work.

As mentioned in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/adoption.html) if you're setting the all the constraints yourself you should probably call `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` otherwise your explicit constraints will conflict with the Autoresizing Mask constraints added implicitly, which looks like what's happening in this case.

EDIT: having seen your edit above listing all the constraints, it confirms what I'm saying. The constraints being added by translating the auto-resizing masks are conflicting with your auto layout constraint. They are explicitly pinning the center Y position of each view in relation to the superview. Try `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` and set any other constraints that you need as required.

Comment: Thanks @mluisbrown, I will follow your suggestion. Anyway, I'm migrating from springs and struts to auto layout (iOS6, not 7) and this is a bit hard to do in code (with IB is pretty straightforward). Do you have a link, some code or a tutorial to illustrate how to position this views using constraints in code? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: I use mostly IB, but whether you use IB or not, I highly recommend reading [Ole Begemann](http://stackoverflow.com/users/116862/ole-begemann)'s post [10 Things You Need To Know About Cocoa Autolayout](http://oleb.net/blog/2013/03/things-you-need-to-know-about-cocoa-autolayout/), the concepts are universal. The Apple Docs on [Visual Format Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH3-SW1) give you an overview of the syntax and how it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

When using auto layout, if you want to re-layout views, you should change the constraints not the view's frame.
You can refer to this sample:

```
#define VIEW_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT   50
#define VIEW_EXPANDED_HEIGHT    100

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHeight1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHeight2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *constraintHeight3;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Create 3 views
    UIView *v1 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v1];

    UIView *v2 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    v2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v2];

    UIView *v3 = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    v3.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v3];

    //Add constraints:
    NSDictionary *variableBindings = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(v1, v2, v3);
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[v1]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:variableBindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[v2]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:variableBindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-20-[v3]-20-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:variableBindings]];
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-60-[v1]" options:0 metrics:nil views:variableBindings]];

    //Combine v1, v2, v3 vertically
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[v1]-0-[v2]-0-[v3]" options:0 metrics:nil views:variableBindings]];

    //Define constraint for v1, v2, v3 height
    self.constraintHeight1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0 constant:VIEW_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintHeight1];
    self.constraintHeight2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0 constant:VIEW_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintHeight2];
    self.constraintHeight3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:v3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:v3 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:0 constant:VIEW_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.constraintHeight3];
}

@end
```

When you want to expand/collapse a view, you can change the value constraint.constant:

```
- (IBAction)clickedBtnExpand:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.constraintHeight1.constant = VIEW_EXPANDED_HEIGHT;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)clickedBtnCollapse:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        self.constraintHeight1.constant = VIEW_COLLAPSED_HEIGHT;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```