# How to adjust equal height AutoLayout multiplier programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Basically I want to expand and collapse a bunch of views using autolayout equal heights multiplier.

I am very new to the iOS-Swift Dev

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271177/animate-with-autolayout

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
let objectA = UIView()
let objectB = UIView()

let views = ["objectA": objectA, "objectB": objectB] // (needed for the second option)

views.values.forEach { 
    view.addSubview($0)
    $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

Option 1:

```
view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: objectA, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: objectB, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

Option 2:

```
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[objectA(100)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[objectB(==objectA)]", options: [], metrics: nil, views: views))
```

Option 3:

```
objectA.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(objectB.heightAnchor).active = true
```

Option 4:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set equal height constraint like this...

```
[parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:childView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:parentView
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                          multiplier:1.0
                          constant:0]];
```

You can also use multiplier by dividing the heights of each view if you want. Try once.